# WiringPi and ADS1115 C/C++ sample programs

Tags: i2c, wiringpi

I am trying to create c++/c program to AnalogRead using and ADS1115. I have seen that wiringPi has support for ADS1115 but i could not find any sample program to start with. Can anybody link guide me to some sample code to read from an ADS1115.

Comment: Jack, I am a python guy and only know about python programming examples, such as those by AdaFruit: https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_ADS1x15/blob/master/examples/simpletest.py. AdaFruit uses libraries so it is easy for newbies to start quickly.  I usually go to their library's GitHub page and learn how they write the init, setup etc, and DIY my own python programs.  I usually think that start prototyping with python, and later "translated" it to C++ is time efficient.

Comment: i am trying to benchmark the language first before fully committing since i would need as fast as possible sampling. I know that python is inherently slow compared to C++ thats why im trying to check if by how much.

Comment: I agree with your approach.  But I vaguely remember ADS1115 max SPS is less than 1k, so it is for sure the bottle neck, and using C++ won't help.

Comment: I might wrongly remember the max sps of ADS1115.  Just now I checked another 24 bit ADC ASD1256 and found it is 30kSPS.  I also remember that 8/12 bit ADC can do 2k SPS, but not sure.

Comment: datasheet say its programmable 8-860 SPS, python produced me only 50 samples in 1 second(by default i did not try to change anything yet) and i need around 300-400. so im seeing what C++ can offer. i would prefer coding it in python too since it makes the other parts of the program easier.

Comment: Well, you remind me those were the days when everybody says assembly language was good because it was time and space efficient, comparing to C.  It is true that assembly language is hard to learn, but it is a necessary evil, otherwise you don't know how to optimize loop efficiency.  Then I used to use macro assembler, which is very high level and easy to program.  But soon came C and C++, where you can write functions and preprocessed macros.  So everybody forgot assembler.  I know Cobol and Fortran are still around, for other reasons.  Now coming back to python, I think history repeats, ...

Comment: I found a C++ sample code now, and the SPS is very inconsistent, from as low as 3SPS upto 120 SPS. very weird, ill now try to increase both language as far as it can go.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100263/discussion-between-tlfong01-and-jack).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100277/discussion-between-tlfong01-and-jack).

Answer (score 3):

I have found this [github](https://github.com/hallgrimur1471/Adafruit_ADS1X15_RPi) that forked the arduino's ads1115 library to be compatible with the raspberry pi.

Comment: Perhaps you can also try ADS1015 which is 3 times faster than ADS1105. https://www.aliexpress.com/w/wholesale-ads1015.html